# Mysql insert new row only if it is different than the previous one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi there I've read a lot of questions about it but I haven't find the answer to my question. The question goes like this:
I have a table in MYSQL with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE`Danni_Prekusvachi` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prekusvach_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `IzkOtZashtita` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `VklPrek` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `cVkl` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `cIzkl` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `greshki` text NOT NULL,
  `komentari` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prava_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `prekusvach_id` (`prekusvach_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Danni_Prekusvachi` (`id`, `prekusvach_id`, `data`, `IzkOtZashtita`, `VklPrek`, `cVkl`, `cIzkl`, `greshki`, `komentari`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-07-25 13:07:24', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'1', '', ''),
(2, 1, '2013-07-25 13:07:25', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'1', '', '');

ALTER TABLE `Danni_Prekusvachi`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Danni_Prekusvachi_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`prekusvach_id`) REFERENCES `Prekusvachi` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I'm inserting data every second or so. I want to insert data **only** if one of the colons 
`IzkOtZashtita`, `VklPrek`, `cVkl` or `cIzkl` has changed its value. 
Right now I am thinking of checking with php whather the last inserted row is the same but my data base will have around 50000 rows so that will get slower as the database gets bigger.

Is there way to do the checking and inserting in one query or I have to call it two times to check the values?

EDIT: I want to insert only if value has changed compared to the last inserted row with the same `prekusvach_id`. So lets say if in one second time the value of cVkl has changed from 1 to 0 I should insert new row. But if the value of cVkl is still the same (1 to 1) the I should not insert new row

Comment: i think its better to select last row first then compare it with new values

Comment: add a unique constraint on thos columns?

Comment: You could make a `composite primary` key and then use `INSERT ... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY `

Comment: What does it means to have `composite primary key` what kind of function does it have?

Comment: one thing that isn't clear to me: you want to insert only if the value of a row has changed. 'Changed' compared to what?

Comment: why would INSERT ... UPDATE work when the OP wants it the other way round ? Insert if the row is different to the one that exists already ?

Comment: Only if value has changed compared to the last inserted row. So lets say if in one second time the value of `cVkl` has changed from `1` to `0` I should insert new row. But if the value of `cVkl` is still the same (`1` to `1`) the I should not insert new row.

Comment: Then you probably want to reconsider your design. Whatever changes those values should also be responsible to log (or whatever you're trying to do) those changes

Comment: @mgrueter I have answered this "The answer to your question is that I read data from modBus and I don't have a way to see event happen I can only see the value"

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers. There are triggers on update. Or you just use a php query which is sipmlear to be set up and check if the values have changes. Database of less then 1 milion record tend to be pretty fast but you should also do a re indexation from time to time so your queries are faster.

Comment: Ok but in this database I will have more than one table one of the tables will have something like 31104000 new records monthly. that will be around 500mb monthly. So the database will become quite large in two or three months.

Comment: Maybe you can check to use long polling( it a constant conection with the database waiting for changes)  maybe it will help you man. I have never dealt with so much data.

Comment: Thank you. I have never dealt with so much data ether. But the project  needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Composite unique constraint.

```
alter table Danni_Prekusvachi add unique index(IzkOtZashtita, VklPrek, cVkl, cIzkl);
```

EDIT:
Than the previous one or than all the previous ones?

Comment: They cant be unique because they have values of only 1 or 0 and I have to record every time one of them has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should tackle this problem at a design stage. From the looks of it, you're trying to insert a new record each second, but only if something happend between those seconds.

Why not insert the record after this specific event (which changes your values) happend?

Comment: The answer to your question is that I read data from modBus and I don't have a way to see event happen I can only see the value.

Comment: ah I see. So if you already have the data, easiest way might be to serialize this data array, save the last one in a variable/session or something like that and compare the next line to this. If the comparsion failes, insert it into the DB. However you do it, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't tackle this at the DB level.

Comment: That one seems prety good Idea. I will try it and then give you feedback.

Comment: OK I have tried to use `SESSION` and `COOKIE` but not they are not working I guess that it is because I execute the script in x-term. that way I can ensure that data will be inserted every second.

Comment: Well then just save the serialized array in a variable. If you're calling your script from x-term, you probably don't need to retain the value over different script calls.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the check to the database layer. So write a procedure that checks if the values have changed and if so add a new row. One call for you and the database is doing the work rather than you.

Comment: Actually IF NOT EXISTS would do this as well. If your table is indexed properly I can't see the danger here. I would suggest you benchmark a few approaches as your worries about time are probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the REPLACE statement, it may be what you are looking for.

[MySQL Manual - REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

Comment: That is close to the thing I am looking for but I want to keep the date colon of the table not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming UID is a sequential running unique ID, you can check the value of a given field from the record where the UID field contains the maximum value and insert the new record only if the value of a given field ('id' in my example), is different than the 'id' field in the last created record.

```
INSERT INTO  'Danni_Prekusvachi' (`id`, `prekusvach_id`, `data`, `IzkOtZashtita`, `VklPrek`, `cVkl`, `cIzkl`, `greshki`, `komentari`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-07-25 13:07:24', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'1', '', ''),
(2, 1, '2013-07-25 13:07:25', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'1', '', '')
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  'Danni_Prekusvachi' WHERE UID = (SELECT MAX(UID)  FROM TABLE)) AS tmp) WHERE NOT tmp.id = id 
)
```